# in a windows form app when user changes a value after previously setting one, can i update an if statement result?

Tags: c#

i have a windows form app (in c#)
with 2 comboboxes, 1 numericUpDown box, 1 textbox.
the user has to choose an input in the first combobox, the second combobox and then choose a value in the numericUpDown.
my program then has to show the result in the textbox.

i used a couple of if statements to display the result.

i know that c# reads the program from top to bottem
and it causes an issue for me.

when the user selects all the options my program will show the correct result, if however the user goes back and changes one of their options, the result is incorrect ( i think it doesn't correctly update the if statement due to c# already being past that part of code?)

i put each if statement in the corresponding "selectedIndexChanged" and "ValueChanged" ( is this the correct way to do it?)

should i use something other than an if statement?
or should i use a "calculate" button, which the user first has to press before showing ANY result?

could i use return or something? i don't really understand those

i tried to set the other bools to false if another one was set to true,  but that didn't do anything.

```
public bool staal = false; //steel
    public bool rvs = false; //stainless
    public string materiaal; 


    public void materiaalDropBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        materiaal = materiaalDropBox.Text; //text currently in combobox
        if (materiaal == "Staal")//material = steel
        { 
            staal = true;
            rvs = false;

        }else if (materiaal == "RVS")
        { 
            rvs = true; // material = stainless
            staal = false;
        }            
    }  

    public string soortboor; //kind of drill
    public bool hss = false; //high speed steel drill
    public bool hardmetaal = false; //cemented carbide drill
    public bool spiraal = false; //basic drill
    decimal VC = 0; // 318 * m/ms of drill on material

    public void soortBoorDropBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        soortboor = soortBoorDropBox.Text;// text currently in combobox
        if (soortboor == "HSS")
        {
            hss = true; // drill is high speed steel
            hardmetaal = false;
            spiraal = false;
        }else if (soortboor == "Hardmetaal")
        {
            hardmetaal = true;// drill is cemented carbide
            hss = false;
            spiraal = false;
        }else if (soortboor == "Spiraal")
        {
            spiraal = true; // drill is normal
            hss = false;
            hardmetaal = false;

        }

        // if material && metal match a certain type, set VC value
        if (rvs && hardmetaal) 
        {
            VC = Convert.ToDecimal(318 * 30);

        }else if (staal && hardmetaal)
        {
            VC = Convert.ToDecimal(318 * 60);
        }else if (staal && hss)
        {
            VC = Convert.ToDecimal(318 * 40);
        }else if (staal && spiraal)
        {
            VC = Convert.ToDecimal(318 * 15);
        }else
        {
            VC = 0;
        }

    }

    public decimal diameter; //drill diameter
    string RPM; //required RPM ( this is the output we want to calculate)

    public void diameterValue_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        diameter = diameterValue.Value; //get diameter value from numericUpDown

        RPM = Convert.ToString(VC / diameter);//convert VC divided by diamter value to string

        toerentalValue.Text = RPM; // show RPM value as string in a textbox

    }
```

Comment: You need to show your current code. We can't guess the mistake you are making and suggest any solution.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i added it now, sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's proper putting all your update code in each `selectedIndex_Changed` event. Change your code to something like this

```
public void materiaalDropBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Set your property values
   UpdateCalculation();
}

private void UpdateCalculation()
{
   //Holds all the other code for calculations
}
```

So each time a `SelectedIndex` changes, you just set the value of the `comboBox` to a private field and then call `UpdateCalculations` to do the remaining job. `UpdateCalculations` then gets those values and work on them.

Comment: do you mean for each indexchanged and value changed i make a seperate  private void?  or for all of them together i make 1 private void?

Comment: nvm, i put all of the calculations in 1 updatecalculation and it works now, i will have to clean up the ifstatements because its a mess now but, THANK you so much